# Does Luke 2:42 contain an example of a dependent clause? Does a dependent clause modify the entire predicate of the independent clause that follows?

Tags: clauses

**Luke 2:42 (KJV) reads:**
And when he was twelve years old, they went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast.

Would "And when he was twelve years old" be considered the **dependent clause** (with "when" being the **subordinating conjunction** and "they went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast" being the **independent clause**)?

Keeping in mind that a sentence featuring a dependent clause followed by a comma and then an independent clause can be rewritten by switching the clauses around and omitting the comma, is it fair to say that the following sentence communicates the same basic idea?

**Re-write:** They went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast when he was twelve years old.

Is it also fair to say that a dependent clause, when paired with an independent clause, becomes a part of the independent clause's predicate through its modification of the stand-alone independent clause's original predicate? With this in mind, does the dependent clause modify the *entire* predicate of the independent clause? Using Luke 2:42 as an example, is "And when he was twelve years old," modifying "went up to Jerusalem after the custom of the feast" here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you asking? That's some of the elementary syntax, it's obvious that the answer is »yes«, so is it a mere confirmation of your own analysis that you need?

Comment: "And" is not part of the dependent clause though.